# Drag and drop between two lists using NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

We have two list of items, items are presented as card. We want to provide drag and drop functionality between two list where user can drag item from one list and drop it into another list.

for example Trello allows user drop card from one list to another.

any help on how this can be achieved in NativeScript/Angular is highly appreciated